# Is there a limitation of using web_accessible_resources locally in developer mode in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

> Invalid value for 'web_accessible_resources[0]'.
>
> Could not load manifest.

Following the docs from chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/

I ended up with a manifest like this:

```
{
  "name": "MyExt",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "Add to MyExt",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png"
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "cookies",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.MyExt.com/"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/logo.png",
      "32": "images/logo.png",
      "48": "images/logo.png",
      "128": "images/logo.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo.png",
    "32": "images/logo.png",
    "48": "images/logo.png",
    "128": "images/logo.png"
  }
}
```

But i cannot test this in developer mode as this below keeps throwing the error quoted at the top:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/*.png"
  ],
```

I have tried using an exact path and all wildcards, a path just to the manifest file. Also tried using a path which is relative to the root of the linux filesystem.. but no matter what i do i get the error.

Comment: It's changed, there's an example in the [official intro](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#web-accessible-resources). Not implemented fully so for now it's something like "web_accessible_resources": [{ "resources": ["foo.html"], "matches": [] }

Comment: that worked, thank you!